# Need copyright to stay on bottom

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here is the html:

```
<div id="terms" class="terms">
        <center><a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
# terms {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;

}

.terms {
width: 100%;
position: relative;
bottom: 5px;
}
```

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? I have tried probably 50 different variations of html and css to get the terms to stay on the bottom of the page, but it is floating around in the center of the page. it will go from the top to the middle to the right and left but i cannot get it to float to the bottom of the page! the entire page is set up as two floating columns `.right` and `.left`

PLEASE HELP!! thank you!

Comment: firstly you have specified two different positions using css style id and class selector to same element. This is not a good practice for using style sheets.

Comment: Can you paste your full html please.

Comment: it wont let me @Exor it is over 5000 characters too long

Comment: First off. You use center tag. Big no no for html5

Answer (score 2):

I've set up a fiddle  for you:

**http://jsfiddle.net/uh53X/1/**

Modify your code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="terms">
  <center><a href="terms.html">Terms & Conditions</a></center>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.terms{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#eee;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i replaced my code with yours and it does the samething. it is centered at the bottom of my screen, but not the bottom of my page.

Comment: then it means, the problem resides in your rest of code. can you paste your full html please.

Comment: it says it is 5000 characters too long

Comment: actually it is http://www.nationalincomenetwork.net/ad-spots.html and /sample-ads.html

Comment: remove position: absolute; from your css. and it goes to bottom.

Comment: i removed positiona and it is still working around the floats. on one page it is squeezed inbetween left and right floats and on the other page it is in between list and floats below it

Comment: http://www.nationalincomenetwork.net/sample-ads.html i dont know how to attach on here

Answer (score 2):

please refer to the below demo

[CLICK HERE FOR DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tfQPz/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="terms">
        <center><a href="terms.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}

#terms {
    position: fixed;
    bottom:5px;
    width: 100%;
    left:0px;
    height:25px;
}
```

---

**UPDATED AS PER THE COMMENT:**

[CLICK FOR DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/tfQPz/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="pageBox">
        <p>
        This is test page height will be managed accordingly and footer will be attached after this box.
        </p>
        <p>
        This is test page height will be managed accordingly and footer will be attached after this box.
        </p>
        <p>
        This is test page height will be managed accordingly and footer will be attached after this box.
        </p>
        <p>
        This is test page height will be managed accordingly and footer will be attached after this box.
        </p>
        <p>
        This is test page height will be managed accordingly and footer will be attached after this box.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="terms">
        <center><a href="terms.html">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></center>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    width:500px;
}

.pageBox{
    height:auto;
}

#terms {
    width: 100%;
    height:25px;
}
```

Comment: this attaches it to my screen, not the page

Comment: Please refer to demo two in my answer above after your comment.

Comment: @ryan : this solution will work. The "terms" div will stick to the bottom of the "pageBox" div. I think that what you are looking for.

Comment: i followed this.... terms & stayed at the top of page, conditions went to the bottom?

Comment: @ryan  is the `width 100%` or is it like you are using `float:left` to your terms div.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to stick the footer to the bottom of the page regardless of how much content you have in it? - [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/), this is what I use for when I want to anchor my footer to the bottom (although from the look of your example pages it might not be what you're after)

or do you just want to make sure it sits underneath the last item in your page? why not just add a clearing div/br underneath your last item and before the terms

```
.clearboth {
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
    clear: both;
    height: 0px;
}

<br class="clearboth" />
```

Then regardless of floats on either side you can just have your div sat underneath that as a regular item

Hope either of these helps